# how to sort card in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

i am beginner in `symfony` and I want to sort (with `SYMFONY` 3) a hand of 10 `cards` (given randomly to the user) according to this order :
Category order : DIAMOND – HEART – SPADES – CLUB.
Value order : AS – 2 – 3 – 4 – 5 – 6 – 7 – 8 – 9 – 10 – JACK – QUEEN – KING .
For exemple : i recover the user’s 10 random cards through a JSON file :

```
{ 
   "cards":[ 
      { 
         "category":"DIAMOND",
         "value":"TEN"
      },
      { 
         "category":"CLUB",
         "value":"ACE"
      },
      { 
         "category":"DIAMOND",
         "value":"QUEEN"
      },
      { 
         "category":"SPADES",
         "value":"SEVEN"
      },
      { 
         "category":"DIAMOND",
         "value":"NINE"
      },
      { 
         "category":"HEART",
         "value":"QUEEN"
      },
      { 
         "category":"CLUB",
         "value":"TEN"
      },
      { 
         "category":"HEART",
         "value":"FIVE"
      },
      { 
         "category":"HEART",
         "value":"SEVEN"
      }
   ]
}
```

The sorted cards become : ACE CLUB /FIVE HEART / SIX  CLUB/ SEVEN HEART / SEVEN SPADES / NINE DIAMOND / TEN DIAMOND /TEN CLUB/ QUEEN  DIAMOND/ QUEEN HEART
I Don’t know how to start ?

Comment: Can you put your sorting algorithm into words, or at least start writing one down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, what you can do is use `usort()` and then apply your logic. In this case I have two arrays of category and values, with their order. Bellow that you can see the `usort` function where it compares the values by the indexes of both arrays. You can make the function smaller, but I wrote it that way to a better understanding:

```
<?php

$category_order = ["CLUB", "SPADES", "HEART", "DIAMOND"];
$value_order = ["ACE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN", "JACK", "QUEEN", "KING"];


$input = '{ 
"cards":[ 
    { 
        "category":"DIAMOND",
        "value":"TEN"
    },
    { 
        "category":"CLUB",
        "value":"ACE"
    },
    { 
        "category":"DIAMOND",
        "value":"QUEEN"
    },
    { 
        "category":"SPADES",
        "value":"SEVEN"
    },
    { 
        "category":"DIAMOND",
        "value":"NINE"
    },
    { 
        "category":"HEART",
        "value":"QUEEN"
    },
    { 
        "category":"CLUB",
        "value":"TEN"
    },
    { 
        "category":"HEART",
        "value":"FIVE"
    },
    { 
        "category":"HEART",
        "value":"SEVEN"
    }
]
}';


$input = json_decode($input, true);
$cards = $input["cards"];

usort($cards, function($a, $b) use ($category_order, $value_order) {
    if (array_search($a['category'], $category_order) > array_search($b['category'], $category_order)) {
        return 1;
    } elseif (array_search($a['category'], $category_order) == array_search($b['category'], $category_order)) {
        if(array_search($a['value'], $value_order) > array_search($b['value'], $value_order)) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
});

print_r($cards);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category] => CLUB
            [value] => ACE
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category] => CLUB
            [value] => TEN
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [category] => SPADES
            [value] => SEVEN
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [category] => HEART
            [value] => FIVE
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [category] => HEART
            [value] => SEVEN
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [category] => HEART
            [value] => QUEEN
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [category] => DIAMOND
            [value] => NINE
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [category] => DIAMOND
            [value] => TEN
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [category] => DIAMOND
            [value] => QUEEN
        )

)
```